# Shall we merge {tikz-chains} into {tikz-pgf}?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Right now we have two questions tagged [tikz-chains](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-chains).  I was first going to post yet another tagging meta question, but I thought I would be bold and say we do not need a tag for individual TikZ libraries.  I would suspect that TikZ experts can answer questions about tikz-chains, and vice versa.

I can't suggest the merge since I don't have a high enough score in the tag to do so (you need a 5 in tag to be merged; my bronze [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf) medal is no good!)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest renaming [tikz-chains](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-chains) into [chains](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chains), for questions about chains in general, such as markow chains and similar diagrams, done with pgf, TikZ, PSTricks, `amscd`, `xy-pic` or any other drawing tool. Tags [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf) and [chains](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chains) are a good tag pair on a question, better than [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf) on its own.

We already have got 328 [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf) questions after some months, I think it's good to have tags for being able to filter. If I would work on a problem with chains, I would be thankful to have such a tag for easy browsing collected questions about chains.

Chains mean a special kind of [diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagrams), but I don't have a problem with it. They are outstanding, as the existence of the Tikz chains library indicates.